# How to get the distinct data from a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, distinct

I want to get **distinct** list from list of persons .

```
List<Person> plst = cl.PersonList;
```

How to do this through `LINQ`. I want to store the result in `List<Person>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Distinct()` will give you distinct values - but unless you've overridden `Equals` / `GetHashCode()` you'll just get distinct *references*. For example, if you want two `Person` objects to be equal if their names are equal, you need to override `Equals`/`GetHashCode` to indicate that. (Ideally, implement `IEquatable<Person>` as well as just overriding `Equals(object)`.)

You'll then need to call `ToList()` to get the results back as a `List<Person>`:

```
var distinct = plst.Distinct().ToList();
```

If you want to get distinct people by some specific property but that's not a suitable candidate for "natural" equality, you'll either need to use `GroupBy` like this:

```
var people = plst.GroupBy(p => p.Name)
                 .Select(g => g.First())
                 .ToList();
```

or use the `DistinctBy` method from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var people = plst.DistinctBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . how about the distinct from a `datatable`

Comment: @just_name: Well I'd personally project into a "real" type first, and then use one of the techniques above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) method, you will need to Implement IEquatable and override equals and hashcode.

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the person' properties are equal. 
        return Code.Equals(other.Code) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashPersonName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field. 
        int hashPersonCode = Code.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the person. 
        return hashPersonName ^ hashPersonCode;
    }
}
var distinctPersons = plst.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) extension method will return an IEnumerable which you can then do a `ToList()` on:

```
List<Person> plst = cl.PersonList.Distinct().ToList();
```